# Adwords API - How to exclude NULL values from an Adwords report using AWQL

Tags: google-ads-api, awql

I am trying to download a [SHOPPING_PERFORMANCE_REPORT](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/reports/shopping-performance-report) with the following fields:

- OfferId
- ProductTitle
- Brand
- Date
- Impressions

For a small subset of records I'm getting empty/blank data for OfferId, ProductTitle, and Brand (only Date and Impressions are not null). I want to exclude NULL OfferId and the filter: `WHERE OfferID != ''` doesn't seem to make any difference. How do I exclude NULL values from my report query??

Answer (score 0):

I ran a similar report for one of our larger shopping accounts, and did not experience the behavior that you describe. So I can't really say how the filtering on those fields is supposed to work.

One thought, though: Is there a possibility that you have a fast-changing inventory and the records that have empty fields refer to products that are no longer in your shopping feed in Merchant Center?

To be honest, I'm not sure if that would cause `OfferId` etc. to be empty, but it would be a potential explanation.